# The number of ways in which n identical items can be divided into r groups so that no group contain less than m items and more than k$(m<k)$ is

Tags: permutations, combinations, binomial-theorem

Please prove this result

> The number of ways in which n identical items can be divided into r groups so that no group contain less than m items and more than k$(m<k)$ is

=Coefficient of $x^n$ in $(x^m+x^{m+1}+...+x^k)$$^r$

---

In my textbook only this result is given it's prove is not given.Maybe because **Binomial Theorem** is our chapter next to **Permutations**.
But I want to know this proof because I am not able to memorize math results or formulae without knowing it's proof.Please help!!!

My attempt: I have no clue about **Binomial Chapter** I just know basic results and formulae.That's why I can't move even a step.Please don't close my question.